# Как открывать базу данных sqlite3 с помощью with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Знаю, что можно базу данных открывать так:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('orders.db')
sql = db.cursor()
...
db.close()
```

Но вроде как лучше будет с помощью `with`. Попробовал сделать так:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('orders.db')
with db.cursor() as cursor:
    ...
```

Но возвращается ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    with db.cursor() as cursor:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Судя по документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager) контекстный менеджер реализован только для объекта типа `sqlite3.Connection`, но не для `sqlite3.Cursor`.

Поэтому можно сделать так:

```
with sqlite3.connect('orders.db') as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(...)
    ...
```

При выходе из блока `with ...` будет автоматически сделан `commit`.

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с контекстным менеджером должны быть реализованы "магические" методы `__enter__` и `__exit__`. В данной библиотеке, если Вы почитаете документацию или посмотрите код, увидите что эти методы не реализованы у объекта `Cursor`. Но реализованы у объекта `Connection`. Так что Вы можете сделать так:

```
import sqlite3


with sqlite3.connect('asd.db') as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT 1;")
    print(cur.fetchall())
```

Вы можете сами создать класс для работы с подключением к sqlite3 и реализовать `__enter__` и `__exit__` методы или с помошью библиотеки `contextlib`.

Comment: "Но реализованы у объекта Connection" - но это для транзакций, а не для автоматического закрытия коннекта

Comment: @vitidev все верно, поправил)